# Change the character in the TextInput in password mode

Tags: apache-flex

I was just curious about the password mode display of the TextInput control in flex. The control displays asterisks instead of the characters themselves when the 'displayAsPassword' is set to true. Quoting the documentation,

> **displayAsPassword** 
>   If true, the field does not display entered text, instead, each text character entered into the control appears as the character "*".

So, is there any way to change this displayed character, unless of course creating a custom component or extending the existing TextInput control?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/439971) provides some suggestions. The easiest is to find a font for which Shift-8 (the asterisk) is the glyph you want.

Comment: I guess extending TextInput is easier than searching for such a font :)

Comment: Perhaps, but not as much fun ;-) Here's a link to 10,000 free fonts - http://ntt.cc/2008/05/17/100000-plus-free-fonts-to-make-your-flex-ui-skins-and-themes-stand-out-from-the-crowd.html

Answer (score 3):

### Just a way to resolve

---

For Flex 4.6

Create a new skin based on TextInput component, "skin_password" or something like that:

[New MXML Skin](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-D0oIW_WtYZ4/VCsNXwBA2xI/AAAAAAAAAZc/sS3jxL_pHag/w519-h495-no/tut02.PNG)

Now, inside the skin, search for this (with some editors you can press **CTRL+O**, write ***textDisplay*** and press **ENTER**):

```
<s:RichEditableText id="textDisplay" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1"
                    verticalAlign="middle" widthInChars="12"
                    left.normal="1" right.normal="1" top.normal="1" bottom.normal="1"/>
```

Add the property **displayAsPassword=true**:

```
<s:RichEditableText id="textDisplay" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1"
                    displayAsPassword="true" verticalAlign="middle" widthInChars="12"
                    left.normal="1" right.normal="1" top.normal="1" bottom.normal="1"/>
```

Search for this method:

```
override protected function initializationComplete():void
    {
        useChromeColor = true;
        super.initializationComplete();
    }
```

Append this line (in my case, a black dot ● instead of the default asterisk *):

```
textDisplay.mx_internal::passwordChar = "●";
```

Now, just set the skinClass attribute to your TextInput component (*my skin example is in the package **skins***):

```
<s:TextInput id="tiPassword" height="30" maxChars="12" skinClass="skins.skin_password" />
```

**And now you have something like this:** [see working](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-tM-d1sropOM/VCsYbeMzZ5I/AAAAAAAAAZ8/kfpf1Yf_X8I/w646-h104-no/tut03.PNG)

### -

### -

### A little more of explanation

---

When you set **displayAsPassword** to *true*, Flex add the textFlow to the RichEditableText contained in the TextInput, with the same number of "password characters".

You can see this in the code of **RichEditableText.as**:

```
public function get text():String 
    {
        // Note: if displayAsPassword, _text will contain the actual text and the text flow will
        // contain the same number of passwordChars.

        // Go to the source if there isn't a pending change.  getText has its own buffering and 
        // only extracts the text from the TextFlow when it is damaged. 
        if (_textContainerManager && !textChanged && !textFlowChanged && !contentChanged && !displayAsPassword)
            return _textContainerManager.getText("\n");

        // Extracting the plaintext from a TextFlow is somewhat expensive,
        // as it involves iterating over the leaf FlowElements in the TextFlow.
        // Therefore we do this extraction only when necessary, namely when
        // you first set the 'content' or the 'textFlow'
        // (or mutate the TextFlow), and then get the 'text'.
        if (_text == null)
        {
            // If 'content' was last set,
            // we have to first turn that into a TextFlow.
            if (_content != null)
                _textFlow = createTextFlowFromContent(_content);

            // Once we have a TextFlow, we can export its plain text.
            _text = staticPlainTextExporter.export(
                _textFlow, ConversionType.STRING_TYPE) as String;
        }

        return _text;
    }
```

In the function **textContainerManager_flowOperationBeginHandler(event:FlowOperationEvent):void**

```
if (_displayAsPassword)
            {
                // Remove deleted text.
                if (delLen > 0)
                {
                    _text = splice(_text, delSelOp.absoluteStart, 
                                   delSelOp.absoluteEnd, "");                                    
                }

                // Add in the inserted text.
                if (textToInsert.length > 0)
                {
                    _text = splice(_text, insertTextOperation.absoluteStart,
                        insertTextOperation.absoluteStart, textToInsert);

                    // Display the passwordChar rather than the actual text.
                    textToInsert = StringUtil.repeat(passwordChar,
                        textToInsert.length);
                }
            }
```

You can see the **passwordChar** variable, it can be accessed with **mx_internal**

```
 /**
     *  @private
     */
    mx_internal var passwordChar:String = "*";
```

Comment: Nice! I don't work with flex anymore, but will be useful for those looking for this.