# How to change Password character in FLEX 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

Hi all I am currently using FLEX version 3.0

It just take a long time to change the Password character currently if i am enabling the displayAsPassword property of TextInput it gives '*' as a password character and I want to change that to '#' so is there any possible way? If possible please tell me...

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367190/change-the-character-in-the-textinput-in-password-mode

Comment: i have searched that but it doesn't give the satisfied answer...

Comment: but i am asking you how to change that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to change the password character for a textfield, but there are 3 ways to fake it.

1. Create a custom PasswordField class which extends TextField and upon text input changes all characters to "#"
2. If you have a font editor create your own custom font in which the * symbol is replaced by # and use that in the textfield instead.
3. Find a font on the internet which does the same as 2. Good luck with that BTW.

Comment: i think 1st one is the best suitable for me... and one question is that how can i change all the characters to "#".

Comment: can't we display that in TextInput? because i have never used TextField and i need to implement that in very short period... so sorry for that but needed. pls give me possible answer for that. Sorry again.

Comment: Ah, sorry hadn't seen you'd tagged it with flex. It should work exactly the same.

Comment: Come to think of it, the code doesn't work. It's a bit more complex.

Comment: when i need to check for the password. At that time shall i get the correct letters that i have typed? I mean to say that if i have typed "asdfg" in passwordField TextInput and when retrieving that shall i get "asdfg" as an output. Currently I am getting "#####" that's why i am asking you. please help me. please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6351/discussion-between-sagar-rawal-and-creynders)